# Signals and Missing Positional Arguments

Tags: python, parameters, pyqt, signals-slots

I developed two windows in QtDesigner (SourceForm, DestinationForm) and used pyuic5 to convert their .ui pages. I am using a third class `WController` as a way to navigate between the two windows using a stacked widget. I have a button in `SourceForm` that populates `treeWidget` with some data and the method `handle_treewidget_itemchange` dictates what happens when a particular item in `treeWidget` gets checked or unchecked by using `self.treeWidget.itemChanged.connect(self.handle_treewidget_itemchange)`. It was my understanding that `itemChanged.connect` would automatically send the row and column of what was changed to the slot but when `handle_treewidget_itemchange(self,row,col)` gets called for the first time, my script crashes with a TypeError:

`TypeError: handle_treewidget_itemchange() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'row' and 'col'`

If I take out the `row` and `col` args, the script runs fine. When I originally had both the method and the call in the `SourceForm` .py file itself, my code worked as intended...maybe this is just a scope issue? I am beginning to think attempting to use PyQt while still inexperienced with Python a bad idea :(

I've tried to strip the code down to the essentials:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from imp_sourceform import Ui_SourceForm
from imp_destform import Ui_DestinationForm


class WController(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WController, self).__init__(parent)
        self.central_widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.sourcewindow = SourceForm()
        self.destinationwindow = DestinationForm()

        self.central_widget.addWidget(self.sourcewindow)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(self.destinationwindow)

        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.sourcewindow)

        self.sourcewindow.selectdestinationsbutton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.navigation_control(1))
        self.destinationwindow.backbutton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.navigation_control(0))

    def navigation_control(self, topage):
        if topage == 1:
            self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.destinationwindow)
        elif topage == 0:
            self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.sourcewindow)

class SourceForm(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_SourceForm):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SourceForm, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.treeWidget.itemChanged.connect(self.handle_treewidget_itemchange) 

    @pyqtSlot()
    def handle_treewidget_itemchange(self,row,col): 
        if row.parent() is None and row.checkState(col) == QtCore.Qt.Unchecked: 
            for x in range(0,row.childCount()):
                row.child(x).setCheckState(0, QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        elif row.parent() is None and row.checkState(col) == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            for x in range(0,row.childCount()):
                row.child(x).setCheckState(0, QtCore.Qt.Checked)
        else:
            pass

class DestinationForm(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_DestinationForm):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DestinationForm, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = WController()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: interestingly, PySide2 does work with a @Slot() decorate with no args, irrespective of the function definition, but PyQt5 does not, as I have found out during a migration from PySide2 to PyQt5. Thanks to this answer for leading me to my problem and solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be careful when using `pyqtSlot`, as it is only too easy to clobber the signature of the slot it is decorating. In your case, it has re-defined the slot as having no arguments, which explains why you are getting that error message. The simple fix is to simply remove it, as your example will work perfectly well without it.

The main purpose of `pyqtSlot` is to allow several different overloads of a slot to be defined, each with a different signature. It may also be needed sometimes when making cross-thread connections. However, these use-cases are relatively rare, and in most PyQt/PySide applications it is not necessary to use `pyqtSlot` at all. Signals can be connected to **any** python callable object, whether it is decorated as a slot or not.

Comment: pyqtSlot creates a real Qt slot, and the connection is broken when the QObject which has the slot is destroyed/garbage-collected (Qt disconnects anything from a deleted QObject). Correct me if I'm wrong, but if not using the `@pyqtSlot`, the connection would not be able to keep track of the QObject, thus just keep a reference to the callable, and thus a reference to the QObject, preventing its destruction. IMHO it's preferrable to use `@pyqtSlot` whenever possible

Comment: Oh god, that's embarrassing, it's working now! Thank you so much! I was just using the `@pyqtSlot()` decorator so I could easily find my slots. I (dangerously) assumed it was benign in that form.

I originally placed the `handle_treewidget_itemchange` method and its connect statement in `SourceForm` (which I quickly learned was a terrible idea once I wanted to tweak the GUI), and the slot received the row and column arguments correctly with the `pyqtslot` decorator intact...that's why I never thought to remove it as a potential fix.

Comment: I've just tested what I said: http://pastebin.com/W5tFkWGL connecting to a true slot doesn't interfere with reference counting, unlike using "any callable" as a slot. So, I really think using "any callable" as a target to `connect` is a bad idea, which should be avoided when possible, replacing it by `pyqtSlot`.

Comment: @λuser. As you can see from the [pyqt docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html#connecting-disconnecting-and-emitting-signals), the API has been specifically designed to take any pythjon callable, and that is how all the example code shown there uses it. So it is in no way a "bad idea" not to use `pyqtSlot` - that is the way the API is intended to be used.

Comment: @ekhumoro yes, you don't have to use `pyqtSlot`, but then it will hold more references than it should, and *that* is problematic, read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38404500/6541288) below

Comment: Thought I would add a note, I am migrating a project from PySide2 to PyQt5. Pyside2 was  happy to have the @Slot() decorator with no args decorating any slot, but PyQt5 is not and the answer is either to put the arguments in the decorator, such as `pyqtSlot(int, int)` or as provided in this answer, remove the decorator altogether.  Thank you to this answer for taking me so quickly to the problem & solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's already an accepted answer to this question but I'll give mine anyway.

The problematic slot is connected to the [itemChanged(QTreeWidgetItem *item, int column)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#itemChanged) signal, so the `pyqtSlot` should look like `@pyqtSlot(QTreeWidgetItem, int)`.

Now, as `ekhumoro` pointed out, PyQt accepts to connect a signal to any Python callable, be it a method, a lambda, or an functor having a `__call__` method. But it's less safe to do so rather than use `@pyqtSlot`.

For example, Qt automatically disconnects when either the source QObject (who would emit the signal) is destroyed, or the target QObject (who has the Qt slot) is destroyed. For example, if you remove a widget, it's not necessary to signal to it that something happened elsewhere. If you use `@pyqtSlot`, a real Qt slot is created in your class, so this disconnection mechanism can apply. Also, Qt doesn't hold a strong reference to the target QObject, so it can be deleted.

If you use any callable, for example a non-decorated, bound method, Qt will have no way to identify the target QObject of the connection. Worse, since you pass a Python callable, it will hold a strong reference to it, and the callable (the bound method) will in turn hold a reference to the final QObject, so your target QObject will not be garbage collected, until you manually disconnect it, or remove the source QObject.

See this code, you can enable one connection or the other, and observe the difference in behavior, which shows whether the window can be garbage-collected or not:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

app = QApplication([])

def create_win():
    win = QMainWindow()
    win.show()

    # case 1
    # app.aboutToQuit.connect(win.repaint)  # this is a qt slot, so win can be deleted

    # case 2
    # app.aboutToQuit.connect(win.size)  # this is not a qt slot, so win can't be deleted

    # win should get garbage-collected here

create_win()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting that we should *never* connect to a callable that isn't decorated as a slot? That seems an arbitrary and completely unnecessary restriction. What about callables that we have no control over, like `win.size` in your own example? The only time you should worry about garbage-collection in a pyqt program is when it starts to cause a real, measurable problem. Your example doesn't show that, so I don't see what point you are trying to make here. The main window should be alive for the lifetime of the application anyway, so it makes little sense to explictly delete it.

Comment: @ekhumoro I'm not saying "never", I say "avoid whenever possible", and in OP's case it's trivial. My example is far-fetched, yes, it's just a minimal testcase demonstrating what I said. No, it's not a real-world instance of the problem, because it subtly happens in more complex scenarios. Here's one: transpose my example with a normal, persistent QMainWindow, and the faulty object is a preferences QDialog. When the preferences dialog is closed, it would not be deleted because a reference would be kept to one of its methods. And then, the QDialog would continue receive signal emissions...

Comment: @ekhumoro I've tried to produce a more-realistic example, and discovered that I was partially wrong: regarding connect-to-an-undecorated-method, Python methods do not hold a reference to the object, but C++ methods do: http://pastebin.com/XS4q2aHu Closing the label will continue printing when a C++ method is used, like `size`, but not with a Python method (like `faultySlot`).

Comment: Like it or not, that is the way the API has been designed. I really don't understand what you find so objectionable about my answer (I assume it was you that downvoted it). There must be literally millions of lines of pyqt/pyside code that never uses slot decorators, and is none the worse for it. After all, it's only releatively recently (PyQt-4.5) that `pyqtSlot` was introduced. The scenarios where it is genuinely needed are relatively rare. When giving advice to beginners, I think it's better to keep things fairly simple and just deal with the actual problem they are trying to solve.

Comment: Back to Qt4, the feature was pretty buggy and I experienced a lot of random **crashes** when connecting signals to lambdas. After a lot of hours tracking the issue, I solved it by replacing those clumsy lambda connects by legit methods with @pyqtSlot. It seems the situation has [improved](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/incompatibilities.html#pyqt-v5-3) with PyQt5, but it's still a half-baked mis-feature with undocumented, hard-to-understand gotchas, so I recommend against using it, to avoid other people saving a few seconds with `@pyqtSlot` but losing hours when it backfires to them.

Comment: I have been writing pyqt/pyside applications since qt3 first appeared and have never had such problems with signal connections. Also, I have read/answered literally thousands of questions in the pyqt tags, including a large number relating to problems with object ownship/cleanup. But I have never seen a single one like you mention. I'm not saying they can't happen (I know they can) - but I'm pretty confident they must be generally quite rare. The only conclusion I can draw from this is that the way you write pyqt programs must be different to the way most other people do.

Comment: Whoah whoah whoah, let's not use this kind of argument "I've always done it this way" or "I've never seen anybody do that". Stackoverflow's not the only source of questions (or articles) on the internet, and we've had different experiences, so I have my reasons advocating that, "let's agree to disagree, etc." Period.