# I am trying to send a siginal with two arguments to a thread but no data is transferd

Tags: python, multithreading, signals, pyqt6

I have requirement to send contently updating string to my thread, that will send it to a pico w.
In the attached snippet, i can send the arguments to a socket in the main window ok. But when sending the same signal to the thread i get an error,
Worker.commData() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'mes' and 'f'.

After trying for several days i have not found a suction. can some one help?

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import sys

# create serial read worker

class Worker(QtCore.QObject):

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.working = True

    def work(self):
        if self.working == True:
       # create test increment timer object
            timerT = QtCore.QTimer(self)
            timerT.timeout.connect(self.comms)
            timerT.start(500) 

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def commData(self, mes, f):
        print(mes)
        print(f)

    def comms(self):
        pass

# Main Window

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    sendReady = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, bool)

    def workStart(self):
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.work)
        self.sendReady.connect(self.printOut)    # connection ok
        self.sendReady.connect(self.worker.commData) # NO DATA
        self.thread.start() 

    # Start Window 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Auto Watering System')       
        self.setMinimumWidth(300)
        self.setMinimumHeight(300)
        self.workStart()
        print("start")
        mes = "99999"
        f = True
        self.sendReady.emit(mes, f)  # connect to pico server

    def printOut(self,mes, f):
        print(mes)
        print(f)
  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

1 move the connect line to efferent places.
2 try with only i argument.

Comment: Typo: you are not declaring the signature of the slot: that decorator should probably be `pyqtSlot(str, bool)`. Be aware that you normally don't need slot decorator at all, as long as the connection is properly done. That said, it's really unclear what would be the purpose of putting that in a thread, and you are also not providing a way to stop and/or destroy the timer, which would probably result in an exception in some situations. For future reference, please try to provide a valid [mre], and always check the syntax in the post preview.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Signals and Missing Positional Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400054/signals-and-missing-positional-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

`self.thread = QThread()` is missing

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I must have copped wrong. it is in the original, that dose not work. so the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use `QtCore.pyqtSlot` decorators, they are optional. But if you use them and slot have arguments, you have to use types as arguments in order for them to work.

```py
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str, bool)
    def commData(self, mes, f):
        print(mes)
        print(f)
```

or

```py
    # no decorator
    def commData(self, mes, f):
        print(mes)
        print(f)
```